# Error while running a .Net code that uses database connectivity in Ubuntu using mono

Tags: mono, dotnet

I am using .Net code in Ubuntu using mono but when I am doing some database connectivity. It is showing error, but it is working correctly in Windows.

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection' from assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.58.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'.
  at TestSqlite.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection' from assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.58.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'.
  at TestSqlite.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: It sounds like you're developing this application yourself. Assuming that is the case, [please show us code that produces the problem](http://www.sscce.org/). (You can [edit] your question to include it.)